# Error when trying to access Wordpress site with WAMP on another computer on local network

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wamp, intranet, local-network

For our business, I'm building a Wordpress intranet site using WAMP. The site works fine from localhost on the server, but if I try it from another computer it returns an error.

Using the IP address (192.168.1.52), I can successfully load the WAMPSERVER Homepage on other computers on the network, but when trying to load the site ("redms"), I get the error shown below. I'm a total novice at this, and I feel like there must be a really easy solution that I'm missing!

[image]

[image]

EDIT:
The `httpd-vhosts.conf` looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName redms
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/redms
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/redms/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

EDIT:
After some searching, I found out that I needed to add the following lines to the `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://192.168.1.52/redms');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://192.168.1.52/redms');
```

And I also needed to change the `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)` in WordPress to: `http://192.168.1.52/redms`.

Comment: Show us the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file please

Comment: I've added it to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

In order for other PC's on your network to be able to see your `redms` site they need to know where it is.

The normal process would be to register the domian name in your local DNS Server so that all the other PC's on your network would be able to look up the domain name and get back the IP Address, just like with any other domain name you enter into you browser.

If you have a local DNS Server on your network, that is the simplest way of doing this. If you do not then you are going to have to edit the HOSTS file on each PC that needs to know how to find the `redms` domain.

Like this

HOST FILE ON EACH OTHER PC on your network

```
192.168.1.52 redms
```

Also you should not be allowing people to see the WAMPServer homepage by entering the IP Address of the WAMPServer PC. So in your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file you should make the localhost inaccessable from another PC by setting the access back to

```
Require local
```

as I assume you have changed it to

```
Require all granted
```

Which is dangerous!

Comment: Thanks, I added the `192.168.1.52 redms` line to the HOSTS file and it sort of worked. But it loads a text-only home page, with no themes or images, and then when I click on a link, it goes to localhost/redms/ which doesn't work.

Comment: UPDATE: I think I've fixed the problem (see edits to original question).
I'd also like to know how to register the domain name in the local DNS server (I could edit the HOSTS file on every computer, but I think it would be more useful to register the domain name as there are a lot of PCs here). I realise this probably isn't the place to ask, but if you could point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Do you have a local DNS Server, if you do it is likely you will have to do this by asking tech support to do it.